# How to update multiple rows in existing table at once in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to update an existing table. Multiple row values are supposed to be updated with the click of the save button in laravel 8.

Here, I have included the codes in store controller.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
             $infos = DB::table('data as dc')
                    ->where('dc.category_id', '=', 1)->select('*')
                    ->orderBy('dc.id')->get();
            $infos_count = count($infos);
    
            if ($infos){
                foreach ($infos as $info) {
                    $info->subject = $request->subject ? $request->subject : null;
                    $info->grade = $request->grade ? $request->grade : null;
                    $info->save();
                }
                Flash::success('updated successfully');
                return redirect('marksheet');
            } else {
                Flash::error('Failed to update');
                return redirect('marksheet');
            }
}
```

The error received is:
[image]

Comment: Use model instead of query builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error because you are trying to update the collection of stdClass objects, which you got from the database.

Try like this:

```
DB::table('data')
    ->where('category_id', '=', 1)
    ->update([
        'subject' => $request->get('subject') ?? null,
        'grade' => $request->get('grade') ?? null
    ]);
Flash::success('updated successfully');

return redirect('marksheet');
```

This will update your records in the database. For the security of valid insert in the database, you can use [database-transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions).

You should read about `update()` in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#update-statements).

Also, using models instead of Query builder is easier. You can read about that in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent).